# Convert video to 10 bit images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, hdr

I have a video with these info:

```
Format : MKV
Codec : HEVC (h.265)
Bit depth : 10 bits
```

How can I get 10-bit frame grabs from it using ffmpeg?

Comment: Which format..?

Comment: @Mulvya - He mentioned it's HEVC (ie, h.265)  I've not particularly worked with h.265 yet, but is more information needed about the h.265 settings to get a frame dump?

Comment: I'm not asking about the input codec, but which output image formats are acceptable? Not all have 10-bit support. And OP's workflow may not support some which do.

Comment: Thanks for all of your responses. The format of output image should be TIFF.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve as much detail as possible, convert it to a 16-bit TIFF, eg:
`ffmpeg -i "DF HDR Sampler.mp4" -pix_fmt rgb48 _Frames/out%05d.tiff`

Example from Digital Foundry's GT Sport HEVC 10-bit H.265 video at https://www.digitalfoundry.net/2017-10-17-free-download-gran-turismo-sport-hdr-sampler

Before (16-bit TIFF framedump, untouched, to 8-bit ProPhoto RGB)

[image: Before Pic]

After (16-bit TIFF framedump, HDR to SDR in Photoshop(eg. Curves and Vibrance adjustments), 8-bit ProPhoto RGB)

[image: After Pic]

Comment: I tried this, but it seems that it creates washed out colors for certain codecs.  Even though the output png file is indeed 16 bpc, the colors do not seem to align with the original video.  See my question here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27991/export-frames-of-10-bpc-video-file-with-ffmpeg